# express.static being overridden by redirect directive in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I am trying to route all requests not specified using

`app.get('*',routes.index);`

However the issue is that none of the statis content (js,css files ) load when an invalid route is entered. However the behaviour is perfectly normal when loading a route which is defined. the entire block of code is specified below

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/dist')));
app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
// set routes
app.get('/',routes.index);
app.get ('/ecommerce/views/:viewname',routes.views);


app.get('/ecommerce/shoppinglist',routes.shoppinglist);
app.get('*',routes.index);
```

Comment: Are you referencing your assets from root `/` from within your views?

Comment: I am referencing them from root

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using `express v3.X` since `v4.X` has deprecated the use of `app.router`.

So, using `node v0.10.18` and `express v3.18.1`

And assuming the following code:

```
var path=require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/dist')));

app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.logger('dev'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('index');
});

app.get ('/ecommerce/views/:viewname',function(req,res){
    res.send('views');
});

app.get('/ecommerce/shoppinglist',function(req,res){
    res.send('shoppinglist');
});

app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.send('default');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And that your working directory is laid out as:

```
server.js
dist/
    foo.txt
```

And that dist/foo.txt contains a single line of text: "this is foo",

Then the following routes produce the expected results:

```
Route                            Result
-------------                    ------------
/                                index
/ecommerce/views/foo             views
/ecommerce/shoppinglist          shoppinglist
/foo.txt                         this is foo
/foo                             default
/bar                             default
/ecommerce                       default
/ecommerce/views                 default
/ecommerce/views/foo/bar         default
```

If your results are different from these, you might consider reloading the express module via `npm install express@"~3"` which will give you the most recent 3.X version, which should be v3.18.1.

Finally, if you wish help with the content of your views, please provide a list of modules you use to create them, or the source of one which fails to load your assets correctly.